# Quality Procedure for Integrated PCB

Tags: pcb, circuit-design, pcb-fabrication, testing

I am working on a Quality Assurance procedure document for PCB integrator. I did some research on the quality standards followed by different companies. But what I could not find was a general and basic procedure by which I (as a client) can evaluate how my PCB manufacturer and integrator have fabricated my PCB post fabrication. P.S. These procedures are just for **Visual Inspection**. I have a separate procedure for Factory Acceptance Test (FAT) where I check the PCB by applying voltage, uploading code and other procedure.

Comment: How can anyone visually inspect inner layers?

Comment: @Andyaka  Apparently people use X-rays to get the inner layer designs.

Comment: @ammar.cma then the OP should fully understand this or only concentrate on two layer designs.

Comment: All my PCB's are 2 layers. What I am asking is a standard procedure for evaluating how good/bad my vendor has fabricated my PCB's

Comment: IPC-A-600 is a good start for bare PCBs. IPC-A-610 is a good start for assembled PCBs. IPC-D-325 may also be applicable. Without knowing what the PCBs need to withstand in service it is difficult to give further guidance.

Comment: Thanks @PeterSmith this sounds just fine. I will have a look.

Answer (score 2):

NASA used to require high-rel PCBs to have a test-frisket off to the side, with vias and traces at tight-spacings.

After the PCB was fabbed, the frisket was removed and SLICED OPEN thru the vias, and the vias' internal plating was examined for proper thickness. Also the connection between vias plating and the laminated foils were scoped for integrity.

For ultimate reliability, JPL required tiny "Z" wires soldered into each via. Only 2-layer PCBs were used, and only tiny amounts of solder were used for weight control. With such redundant methods, satellites last for 50+ years.